# css prevent li from wrapping when zooming in

Tags: css

I created a simple menu using CSS and I don't face any problem but whenever I zoom in the button inside the menu is wrapping, how I can make the buttons of the menu in the same line without wrapping and going to second line.

any help will be appreciated.

here is my code:

```css
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px 0;
  background: #e3d678;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu' dir="ltr">
  <ul>
    <li runat="server" class='active'> <a href='' "><span></a></li>    
    <li  runat="server "  >   <a href=''"><span></a></li>    
    <li  runat="server" >   <a href=''"><span></a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line, the extra lines will not be broken and the extra lines will not be displayed.　　　
Feel free to change the width.

```
#cssmenu ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px 0;
  background: #e3d678;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay I tried the code but the same problem happens

Comment: It wasn't text. How about this?